# How to get two templated classes implicitly convertible to one another

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11

I have recently encountered a scenario which causes the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 compiler to produce an internal error (`C1001: An internal error has occured in the compiler.`).

If we have the header file `Foo.h`:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "Bar.h"

template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
      operator Bar<T>() const
      {
          Bar<T> bar;

          for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
               bar.m_tArray[i] = m_tArray[i];

          return bar;
      }

private:
      template <typename U>
      friend class Bar<U>;

      T m_tArray[5];
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

And `Bar.h`:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

#include "Foo.h"

template <typename T>
class Bar {
public:
      operator Foo<T>() const
      {
          Foo<T> foo;

          for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
               foo.m_tArray[i] = m_tArray[i];

          return foo;
      }

private:
      template <typename U>
      friend class Foo<U>;

      T m_tArray[5];
};

#endif // BAR_H
```

I can then cause the error by instantiating either class, for instance:

```
int main() {
    Foo<int> foo;
}
```

I'm guessing the error is occurring because each class refers to the other's definition within it's own definition and so there is an infinite recursion depth; however, I'm not sure how to resolve this problem as I can only have templates defined inline; I can not declare them and then define them elsewhere (when both templates have been declared and the internals exposed to one another).

Comment: An internal compiler error is (almost) always a bug in the compiler.

Comment: Isn't there a forward-declaration missing?

Comment: `template <typename U> friend class Foo<U>;` is illegal, as far as I can tell. You could use `friend class Foo<T>;` instead, which requires a forward-declaration.

Comment: @dyp an internal compiler error is often a stack overflow in template recursion

Comment: @pqnet I have seen g++ and clang++ specifically complain about template recursion depth. Not sure about MSVC. I think you can produce ICEs when exceeding the implementation's limits; it would be nice if such a case were diagnosed, but that might be impossible at least in some cases.

Comment: An internal compiler error is (1) never your fault (2) a result of a compiler bug (3) useless to theorize about. Submit a bug report to Microsoft. However, what you have here is two headers mutually including each other. This can never work. You need to rework this into forward declarations. As a side note, you probably should not have both include guards and `#pragma once`, this is redundant.

Comment: @Shaktal I copied and pasted your code in visual-c++ and it didn't give me the same error as you have. Please post a reproducible example

Comment: @pqnet What version of Visual C++ are you using? This error is reproducible in Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 (without CTP), I don't know about other versions?

Comment: @n.m. the `windows.h` header uses both `#pragma once` and `#ifdef` guards. I guess it's good practice to include both

Comment: @Shaktal I used Visual Studio 2012 update 4. It reports correctly that the class that ends up first in your final file depends on something that is not defined yet. It may be a bug with how the compiler reports the error, but this code is not supposed to work as it is.

Comment: @pqnet I'm not sure you can mention `windows.h` and good practice in the same sentence.

Comment: @pqnet But that is my question; I assumed that was why the bug occurred, I was asking what the best way to fix it would be (as templates must be defined inline, one will always be defined before the other?) I can get around it by using `friend class Foo<T>;` but then I can only convert to the same templated type?

Comment: @n.m. Since `#pragma once` is a (useless) Microsoft extension, I would expect that we shouldn't teach them how to use it.

Comment: @pqnet `#pragma once` is anything but useless and supported by [many compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability).

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi That's no evidence of anything. Compilers that don't play nice with Windows sources and/or Windows mindset just don't stand a chance, so we have a very biased sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use forward declaration for your template classes. Example:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo;

template <typename T>
class Bar {
      template <class U>
      friend class Foo;
public:
      operator Foo<T>() const
      {
          Foo<T> foo;

          for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
               foo.m_tArray[i] = m_tArray[i];

          return foo;
      }

private:

      T m_tArray[5];
};

template <typename T>
class Foo {
      template <class U>
      friend class Bar;
public:
      operator Bar<T>() const
      {
          Bar<T> bar;

          for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
               bar.m_tArray[i] = m_tArray[i];

          return bar;
      }

private:

      T m_tArray[5];
};


int main() {
    Foo<int> foo;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have `Foo<T>` and `Bar<U>` as friend classes for all possible combinations of `T` and `U`? I.e. have `Foo<float>` a friend of `Bar<int>`?

Comment: Yes, you say `template<typename U> friend class Foo;` (note not `Foo<U>`).

Comment: @Shaktal sorry, I guessed wrong what you wanted to do. Updated